# sudo npm install create-react-app -g throws error(Ubuntu)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ubuntu-16.04

```
sudo npm install create-react-app -g
```

throws this error:

```
npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 while parsing near '<!DOCTYPE html>npm ERR! <ht...'
```

node version 10.8.0

npm version 6.2.0

Os Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before using `sudo npm install create-react-app -g`

use `npm cache clean --force`, It should work, i tried it before. For more reference you can visit [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19072).